# How to create a report for products with scheduled revenue?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, product, schedule

I am trying to create a report to forecast monthly revenue with products that have a schedule.

As you can see in the example below, monthly revenue is calculated based on the total product amount (including future revenue), not based on the month when it is scheduled to occur.

Thanks!

[image: Example]